# Sort 3D array by specific dimension and element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, numpy-ndarray

if I have a 3D array;
such as:

```
[
  [
    [10,2],
    [5,3],
    [4,4]
  ],
  [
    [7,6],
    [4,2],
    [5,8]
  ]
]
```

I want to sort them according to **3rd dim & 1st value.**

It means, the result should be

```
[
  [
    [4,4],
    [5,3],
    [10,2]
  ],
  [
    [4,2],
    [5,8],
    [7,6]
  ]
]
```

How could I make it in python?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is by using the list.sort method or the sorted function together with an appropriate value of the *key* parameter (see the documentation:[howto/sorting](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)).

The Python documentation does a great job explaining the purpose of *key* parameter:

"Both list.sort() and sorted() have a *key* parameter to specify **a function** to be called on **each list element prior** to making comparisons."

For example, let us sort the first item of your list:

```
first=[[10, 2], [5, 3], [4, 4]]

def by_first(element):

    """
    Sort a two-dimensional list by the first element 

    Param: element of the list i.e [10, 2]
    Return: first item of element
    """

    return element[0]
```

So, to sort the above list  we do this

```
sorted(first,key=by_first)
```

Finally, to solve the initial problem(three-dimensional list) we just have to do the above for **each item of your list**

```
list_numbers = [[[10, 2], [5, 3], [4, 4]], [[7, 6], [4, 2], [5, 8]]]

[sorted(entry, key=by_first) for entry in list_numbers]
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below is a simple workaround to achieve the desired output.

```
list= [[[10,2],[5,3],[4,4]],[[7,6],[4,2],[5,8]]]

for i in range(len(list)):
    list[:][:][i].sort(key=lambda x: x[:][:][0])

print(list)
```

Through each iteration of the for loop, the elements are sorted one list at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something more related to arrays (not lists) you can try the following:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[10,2],
               [5,3],
               [4,4]],

              [[7,6],
               [4,2],
               [5,8]]])
b = np.zeros(a.shape)

sorted_idx = np.argsort(a, axis=1)

for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        b[i, j] = a[i, sorted_idx[i, j, 0]]

print(b.astype(int))

# [[[ 4  4]
#   [ 5  3]
#   [10  2]]
# 
#  [[ 4  2]
#   [ 5  8]
#   [ 7  6]]]
```

Note that actually, according to your expected output, you need to sort by the first element of `axis=1` not the last axis.